# Module Not Found Error (Simple Mistake). I cannot find why my module is not found and I believe it has to do with PATH

Tags: python, path

I already pip installed pixabay but I am getting an error.

```
import pixabay.core

# init pixabay API
px = pixabay.core("API KEY")

# search for space
space = px.query("space")

# get len of hits len(space)
print("{} hits".format(len(space)))

# download first image
space[0].download("space.jpg", "largeImage")
```

I know the answer is simple but I don't know it. I am new to Python.

I've tried reinstalling it, and have checked for any errors in my typing but I believe it is all good. I think it has something to do with PATH but I really don't know what that means.

Comment: How are you running the script, and how are you running the pip install? Maybe the version of pip you used to install pixabay doesn't line up with the version of python you're using to run the script. Check that `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"` lists out the same folder that pip is in (find pip's folder using `pip --version`.

Comment: You need to look at PYTHONPATH, not PATH.